# Convert DataFrame to JSON Arrays with Python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have this DataFrame:

```py
             A       B        C        D
16         USA    15.5     10.8      4.7
15     Germany    17.7     12.3      5.3
```

I would like to create a JSON file that looks like so:

```json
"data": [
   ["A", "B", "C", "D"],
   ["USA", "15.5", "10.8", "4.7"],
   ["Germany", "17.7", "12.3", "5.3],
]
```

`to_dict()` or `to_json()` do not seem to work.

This does work:

```py
numpy_array = df.to_numpy()
column_headers = df.columns.values.tolist()
array_with_headers = numpy.vstack([column_headers, numpy_array])
json_object = {}
json_object["data"] = array_with_headers.tolist()
```

...is kind of complicated though. Any idea how I can achieve this without numpy? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert each row to `list` using `apply` and then call `to_list()`, that will give you data in list, on which you can call `json.dumps`

```py
import json
json.dumps({'data': df.reset_index(drop=True).T.reset_index().T.apply(list,axis=1).to_list()})
```

**Output**:

```py
'{"data": [["A", "B", "C", "D"], ["USA", 15.5, 10.8, 4.7], ["Germany", 17.7, 12.3, 5.3]]}'
```

PS: `reset_index()` and trasnpose `T` has been used just to bring column name in the first row.

Comment: Awesome - thank you! Can you easily prettify the JSON with json.dumps (i.e. remove backslashes, line breaks with indent=1 instead of \n)?

Comment: That becomes a new question, you can ask on SO, someone will definitely answer it